# How can I stop notifying my connections that I have new LinkedIn connections?

Tags: linkedin

A while ago I wondered how LinkedIn (mis)uses my data. I signed up for an extra account, added it as a connection, and checked its mailbox to see what LinkedIn sends that account about me.

Sure enough, despite that I have the share/notify options off [image: settings to share information on linkedin]  in the LinkedIn settings, my imaginary connection continues to receive messages from LinkedIn "Sam has 7 new connections", along with an accompanying "Expand your network" button.

This is particularly undesirable because those who expand their network may very well be doing it because they are hunting for better opportunities, and they may not want to broadcast to colleagues (who are likely already connections) that they are hunting. (Someone determined to track can of course still do so unless the list of connections is completely private; but, likely, few would bother.)

How can I (in April 2020) turn off notifications of new connections? LinkedIn itself has an ever so (*un*)helpful help page that [purports](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/1602) to discuss precisely that. I'm asking in April 2020. From previous experience, this changes rapidly.

[Another page](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/turn-off-your-activity-broadcast-feed-before-you-start-pierson/) shows a button

[image: notify-your-network button]

to notify one's network with changes. Where is this button?